# Stop geom_density_ridges from showing non-existent tail values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges, ridgeline-plot

When I use `geom_density_ridges()`, the plot often ends up showing long tails of values that don't exist in the data.

Here's an example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

data("lincoln_weather")

# Remove all negative values for "Minimum Temperature"
d <- lincoln_weather[lincoln_weather$`Min Temperature [F]`>=0,]

ggplot(d, aes(`Min Temperature [F]`, Month)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height=.01)
```

[image: geom_ridgline]
As you can see, January, February, and December all show negative temperatures, but there are no negative values in the data at all.

Of course, I can add limits to the x-axis, but that doesn't solve the problem because it just truncates the existing erroneous density.

```
ggplot(d, aes(`Min Temperature [F]`, Month)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height=.01) +
  xlim(0,80)
```

[image: geom_ridgeline with axis limits]
Now the plot makes it look like there are zero values for January and February (there are none). It also makes it look like 0 degrees happened often in December, when in reality there was only 1 such day.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you don't want a density estimate? What exactly are you expecting? Most density estimators assume your data is continuous over all real numbers. They don't expect a bounded range. You would need some kind of different estimator for that. because right now there is nothing to "fix," the statistical method is working as it was designed.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I guess a histogram would make more sense for a bounded range.

This problem arose because I was working with data that can't have negative numbers but does have many zero and near-zero numbers. I suppose a density plot just isn't the right tool to visualize that.

Comment: @MrFlick Actually, cutting density estimates at the ends of the data ranges is not that unusual. Violin plots usually do this. The same can be done with `stat_density()`, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50011428/4975218)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One option is to use `stat_density()` instead of `stat_density_ridges()`. There are some things that `stat_density()` can't do, such as drawing vertical lines or overlaying points, but on the flip side it can do some things that `stat_density_ridges()` can't do, such as trimming the distributions to the data ranges.

```
# Remove all negative values for "Minimum Temperature"
d <- lincoln_weather[lincoln_weather$`Min Temperature [F]`>=0,]

ggplot(d, aes(`Min Temperature [F]`, Month, group = Month, height = ..density..)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "density", trim = TRUE)
```

[image]

As an alternative, you could draw a point rug, maybe that serves your purpose as well or better:

```
ggplot(d, aes(`Min Temperature [F]`, Month)) +
  geom_density_ridges(rel_min_height = 0.01, jittered_points = TRUE,
                      position = position_points_jitter(width = 0.5, height = 0),
                      point_shape = "|", point_size = 2,
                      alpha = 0.7)
```

[image]

Note: those two approaches cannot currently be combined, that would require some modifications to the stat code.

Comment: You can combine the two approaches adding new point layers with new aesthetics: `... + geom_points(aes(\`Min Temperature [F]\`, Month), inherit.aes = F, ...)`

Answer (score 9):

Well, turns out I should have just read [the documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html) more closely. The key part is:

> "The ggridges package provides two main geoms, geom_ridgeline and
>   geom_density_ridges. The former takes height values directly to draw
>   ridgelines, and the latter first estimates data densities and then
>   draws those using ridgelines."

There are multiple ways to handle this issue. Here is one:

```
ggplot(d, aes(`Min Temperature [F]`, Month, height=..density..)) +
  geom_density_ridges(stat = "binline", binwidth=1,
                      draw_baseline = F)
```

[image]